# How to Stop any other function when a specific function is running

Tags: javascript, html, function, return, preventdefault

I have this modal that slides in from the top. It works fine but I have other function too which is being clicked and hover when the modal layout is shown. I want to know, how do I stop those functions when this one is running? I have looked at `preventDefault` and `return` statement but I don't know how to use it if that would solve the issue. And also I would like to know if there is a better way to simplify this code.

```js
var remove = document.querySelector('.remove');
var modal = document.querySelector('#project-layout');
var innerlayout = document.querySelector('#appended-layout');
var project = document.querySelectorAll('#project-grid');
for (var i = 0; i < project.length; i++) {
  project[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target === project[0]) {
      var tag = '<div class="layer1"><span>Ecommerce Store</span></div><div class="layer2"><h4>Description</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ante lorem, ullamcorper id lorem quis, pharetra fringilla risus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent cursus leo sem, eget pulvinar neque pretium et. Mauris ac arcu velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></div><div id="list"><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul></div><div id="show-on-lgsrn"><a href="./projects/web-store/E Store.html" target="_blank"><button>Show Site</button></a></div>';
      innerlayout.innerHTML = tag;
      modal.style.top = '20%';
    } else if (e.target === project[1]) {
      var tag = '<div class="layer1"><span>Food Site</span></div><div class="layer2"><h4>Description</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ante lorem, ullamcorper id lorem quis, pharetra fringilla risus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent cursus leo sem, eget pulvinar neque pretium et. Mauris ac arcu velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></div><div id="list"><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul></div><div id="show-on-lgsrn"><a href="./projects/web-store/E Store.html" target="_blank"><button>Show Site</button></a></div>';
      innerlayout.innerHTML = tag;
      modal.style.top = '20%';
    } else if (e.target === project[2]) {
      var tag = '<div class="layer1"><span>Real Estate Site</span></div><div class="layer2"><h4>Description</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ante lorem, ullamcorper id lorem quis, pharetra fringilla risus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent cursus leo sem, eget pulvinar neque pretium et. Mauris ac arcu velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></div><div id="list"><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul></div><div id="show-on-lgsrn"><a href="./projects/web-store/E Store.html" target="_blank"><button>Show Site</button></a></div>';
      innerlayout.innerHTML = tag;
      modal.style.top = '20%';
    } else if (e.target === project[3]) {
      var tag = '<div class="layer1"><span>Online Course Site</span></div><div class="layer2"><h4>Description</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ante lorem, ullamcorper id lorem quis, pharetra fringilla risus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent cursus leo sem, eget pulvinar neque pretium et. Mauris ac arcu velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></div><div id="list"><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul></div><div id="show-on-lgsrn"><a href="./projects/web-store/E Store.html" target="_blank"><button>Show Site</button></a></div>';
      innerlayout.innerHTML = tag;
      modal.style.top = '20%';
    } else if (e.target === project[4]) {
      var tag = '<div class="layer1"><span>Ecommerce Store</span></div><div class="layer2"><h4>Description</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ante lorem, ullamcorper id lorem quis, pharetra fringilla risus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent cursus leo sem, eget pulvinar neque pretium et. Mauris ac arcu velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></div><div id="list"><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul></div><div id="show-on-lgsrn"><a href="./projects/web-store/E Store.html" target="_blank"><button>Show Site</button></a></div>';
      innerlayout.innerHTML = tag;
      modal.style.top = '20%';
    } else if (e.target === project[5]) {
      var tag = '<div class="layer1"><span>Ecommerce Store</span></div><div class="layer2"><h4>Description</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ante lorem, ullamcorper id lorem quis, pharetra fringilla risus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent cursus leo sem, eget pulvinar neque pretium et. Mauris ac arcu velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></div><div id="list"><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul></div><div id="show-on-lgsrn"><a href="./projects/web-store/E Store.html" target="_blank"><button>Show Site</button></a></div>';
      innerlayout.innerHTML = tag;
      modal.style.top = '20%';
    } else if (e.target === project[6]) {
      var tag = '<div class="layer1"><span>Ecommerce Store</span></div><div class="layer2"><h4>Description</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ante lorem, ullamcorper id lorem quis, pharetra fringilla risus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent cursus leo sem, eget pulvinar neque pretium et. Mauris ac arcu velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></div><div id="list"><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul></div><div id="show-on-lgsrn"><a href="./projects/web-store/E Store.html" target="_blank"><button>Show Site</button></a></div>';
      innerlayout.innerHTML = tag;
      modal.style.top = '20%';
    } else if (e.target === project[7]) {
      var tag = '<div class="layer1"><span>Ecommerce Store</span></div><div class="layer2"><h4>Description</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ante lorem, ullamcorper id lorem quis, pharetra fringilla risus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent cursus leo sem, eget pulvinar neque pretium et. Mauris ac arcu velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></div><div id="list"><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul><ul><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li><li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li></ul></div><div id="show-on-lgsrn"><a href="./projects/web-store/E Store.html" target="_blank"><button>Show Site</button></a></div>';
      innerlayout.innerHTML = tag;
      modal.style.top = '20%';
    }
  })
}

remove.addEventListener('click', function() {
  modal.style.top = '-80%';
})
```

Please let me know if other functions code is needed. any help would be appreciated

Comment: JavaScript runs in a single-threaded environment - - only one line can be running at any one time. You cannot therefore have a line of code executed that stops another line that is already being executed. The only way a function can be stopped early is with a `return` or by throwing an exception.

Comment: Your code is a bit hard to read with all the lorem ipsum in there!

Comment: Do you mean prevent user clicking on something else? Not really clear what "stop function" means

Comment: Yes, charlietfl. that's what i mean i think i have to just create a window size div and make the visibility to hidden.

Comment: Kokodoko . sorry for that brother.

Comment: What's the 'other' function look like then?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of the issue. Please do note the "Minimal" part of that; we likely don't need all of that code to reproduce the issue of not being able to stop code from running.